# Order of verbs in this sentence

Tags: word-order

In [The 'death' of Windows Nano Server](https://www.brianmadden.com/opinion/The-death-of-Windows-NanoServer), I see "Dude, were you wrong":

> For about a year before Nano’s release in the Tech Preview builds of Server 2016, it was completely embraced by Microsoft as the ultimate small-footprint and low-patch version of their kernel. Jeffrey Snover even remarked that it would be “the future of the Windows Server OS.”
>   (Dude, were you wrong.)

IMHO right is "you were wrong". If it is not a question. But no '?', so it's not a question. How will be right?

Comment: Thanks, but please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/36187) before accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question. Actually, it's inverted for emphasis. I read it with the "you" being stressed, and I think it would benefit from being italicized. I feel like it's roughly the same as "you were really wrong":

> Dude, were *you* wrong.
>   → Dude, you were really wrong.

The author is poking fun at "you", "you" being Jeffrey Snover.